# Php Error 404 when redirecting from home page

Tags: php, indexing, hyperlink, html

I am trying to add a link to a different page of my website, but when I click the link, it gives me a "404 Page Not Found" error.

Goal: All I want to do it be able to link my home page, index.php, to other pages of my website, like contact.php, about.php.

**Code of the page I want to link to** is in the "public_html folder of my file manager.  This code is actually a copy of the about.php page.  I thought I would just change the name of file,upload it the file manager and then change the code :

```
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                About Us
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Intro Content -->
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">

<strong><u>Mission Statement</u></strong><br />

</P>

<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>
```

### What I've tried:

1. the htaccess page says "Deny From All"
2. The permissions of all pages including index.php is 755
3. taking the html links out of the php page
4. I can link to contact.php, about.php just fine, but when I replace the file names to something different, it gives me the 404 not found error.
   Your help is much appreciated!!

---

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Angel Application is a free online database/website designed for students, who can exchange,sell, or donate textbooks.">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="ZC66iDvmwxnyIuvY7aPWACB0PVQzAgh7ykwIlDSfDXc" />
    <title>Angel Application</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="<?php echo base_url();?>font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
<script src="<?php echo base_url();?>js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>images/AngelLogo.png" alt="Angel" title="Angel Application" height="63" width="300" align="left" style="margin: 2px 8px 2px -15px;"/> </a>

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li>
                        <?php if($this->session->userdata('public_logged_in')==TRUE){?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/logout">Hi <?php echo $this->session->userdata('public_username');?> &nbsp;|&nbsp;Logout</a>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/myhome">My Account</a>
                        <?php }else{?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login">Login</a>
                        <?php }?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>sample2">Upload</a>
                     </li>

                </ul>
            </div>
             <div>
            <li>

           </li>
            </div>

<!---
           div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li>
                        <?php if($this->session->userdata('public_logged_in')==TRUE){?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/logout">Hi <?php echo $this->session->userdata('public_username');?> &nbsp;|&nbsp;Logout</a>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/myhome">My Account</a>
                        <?php }else{?>
                            <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login">Login</a>
                        <?php }?>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/contact">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>

                    </li>
                     <li>

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </div>

    --->
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>

        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Header Carousel -->
    <header id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
        <!-- Indicators -->


        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('<?php echo base_url();?>images/Andoverharvard.jpg');"></div>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h4>A free and non-profit platform for exchanging, selling and donating books</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </header>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
    <br />
    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message'); ?>
```

Comment: Sorry the header, footer, and mission statement  should all be part of the code block

Comment: I'm assuming your `header` and  `footer` have a file extension that you are leaving off? (such as header.php etc)

Answer (score 1):

A 404 isn't likely from your htaccess file.  It just means that you are pointing to a file that is not there.

Your problem most likely is in how you are calling the remote scripts.

This line should probably be something like (assuming that the file you are calling is a php file)

```
<?php $this->load->view('header.php'); ?>
```

the same thing is likely true for the footer.

**Edit**

Your problem is with these rows:

```
                <li>
                    <?php if($this->session->userdata('public_logged_in')==TRUE){?>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/logout">Hi <?php echo $this->session->userdata('public_username');?> &nbsp;|&nbsp;Logout</a>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login/myhome">My Account</a>
                    <?php }else{?>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login">Login</a>
                    <?php }?>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/contact">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>sample2">Upload</a>
                 </li>
```

You are treating index.php as a directory;  it's wholly unnecessary because you are already echoing the base URL (which may not even be necessary at all, unless you are referencing these from a directory other than the root one.  If that's the case, then yes, this is fine).  Change all of these rows to something like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/login/logout"
```

Note, you may also be having a problem like this with your footer file

Comment: Thanks nomistic!   Does it matter where the file is?  What I mean is that I have it in public_html.   Also, all my other php pages, contact.php, about.php all have the following line:   **<?php $this->load->view('header.php'); ?>**  When I link to those pages, everything works fine.  However, when I change the link to this particular page, I still get the same error

Comment: It shouldn't however if you are getting a 404, it is pointing to a place where the file is not.  Check your URL to see where the script is directing.   Is the file in that folder?  If not, change the location in the script (or move the file, but that's more like moving the piano to be closer to the bench ;) )

Comment: I know you said the htaccess shouldn't be a factor, but I should mention that I added the following to the htaccess file:

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: like I mentioned, check the URL for the 404 page.  

If you want to be sure, remove the htaccess file and see if it works.

Comment: I think I may have figured out the problem.   The <a href> of my other pages say something like this: <a href="angelapplication.org/index.php/contact"></a>  while the page I'm having trouble with says <a href="angelapplication.org/email">  The index.php is not a folder, but a file, correct?  How would I fix this?  Thanks

Comment: yes, index.php  is a file and not a folder.  Is it working without the htaccess?  Also if you show the contents of your header.php file that might help track it down.

Comment: There are no differences without the htaccess file..but here is the header script

Comment: aha, I see your problem lines.   It's all the ones that state:  ` <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/login`  etc.    you are treating `index.php as a directory.  Remove the `index.php` from these rows, as you are likely already including that with the php row.  I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Nomistic,

I thought since you spent some time on my problem, it's only fair for me to post the solution.  After trying what we discussed, I still could not get it to work. Since I was not the one to build this site, I finally decided to ask my web designer.

This is what he wrote:

- This website is developed with MVC framework.
- If you want to create a page follow the below steps.
- First go to /public_html/application/controllers
- Create a file email.php (this will behave as a controller). open the
  file and have a look.
- Here index method is the one which will be called by default.
- In this method, use this line to load a file
  "$this->load->view('emailform');". Here the emailform is the file name
  that you create in this path /public_html/application/views/
- finally you call that controller file, not the file itself.

Again, thanks for  your help!